# how to raise exception with two values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know I can do in `plpgsql`: `RAISE Exception '%', variable_name;`

But I need to raise exception with two values:

```
raise exception 'values %, % are incorrect please check.'(val1,val2);
```

No matter what I try I still get `syntax error`

Manual doesn't say how to do it:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

How do I set it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed`,`

```
raise exception 'values %, % are incorrect please check.',val1,val2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raise exception 'values %, % are incorrect please check.', val1, val2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does:

> RAISE [ level ] 'format' [, expression [, ... ]] [ USING option =
>   expression [, ... ] ];

[, ...] stands for more expressions so

```
raise exception 'values %, % are incorrect please check.',val1,val2;
```

should work.